# Newly Invented Card Game Hand Ranking

Tags: probability, card-games

What would single-deck 2-card poker rankings/probability be for the following hands.

(Deal 2 cards)

### Hands

- Royal Flush - Ace King Suited
- Pair
- Straight Flush - Any consecutive suited
- Flush - Any suited cards
- Straight - Any 2 consecutive cards
- (High Card)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention, the ranking would be inversely proportional to the probability, which is proportional to the number of hands of given type. In order to encourage you to calculate these yourself, here are the ordered counts (ignoring card order), ignoring (high card):
$$ 4, 44, 78, 144, 264. $$
Note that these are not given in the same order as your list! If your counts turn out differently, it might be my mistake, or you might be double counting (say counting a royal flush as a straight flush and a flush).

A particularly simple way to do the calculation is to go over all $52\cdot 51/2 = 1326$ possible hands and classify them using a computer program. This way you don't even have to think, just program.

Comment: I appreciate it!  Very helpful.  Maybe I'll crunch the numbers when I'm not so busy :)  I posted it out of pure laziness.  It's just a friendly game we play in the office.

Comment: (4)   Royal Flush - Ace King Suited 
(44)  Straight Flush - Any consecutive suited
(78)  Pair
(144) Straight - Any ceonsecutive cards
(264) Flush - Any suited cards
High Card